# Cleaning up overlapping meshes

Tags: mesh

I'm building a human spine, was trying to keep the polycount as low as possible in order to get a usable result for texturing right away. I used single torus objects for the spinal discs, now In order to give the spine its natural curve (built it vertically straight thinking it makes the most sense) I'd have to join all vertebraes and discs to one object, which leaves me with quite a chaos of overlapping mesh everywhere.

[image]

[image]

Wondering if it was a mistake to build it with single objects...
What is the best way to get this halfway clean so it's usable for decent texturing? Retopologizing the whole thing the "old fashioned" way?
I was somehow thinking the Quad Remesher would clean up the surface/the overlapping parts, basically retopologizing only the surface, but it seems to remesh the internal stuff as well, just as it is:
[image]

Still kind of new to a lot of things in 3d, so any advice is greatly appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You may use [Shrinkwrap modifier](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/modifiers/deform/shrinkwrap.html).

You should separate each part using "P" because the modifier is working between different objects.

You can find the balance between the settings, offset, even using a group of vertices, to have a gap between the two meshes.

The original mesh:
[image]

An example of the result using Shrinkwrap:
[image]

Notice on the right part: a poor vertex count or a wrong topology do not allow the modifier to manage the gap as expected.

> Depending on the position of the vertices and the different topology,
> you may need to modify or add/remove some loops.

Comment: Ah of course that would have been an option! Thanks for the advice. I went by using the boolean, step by step unifying all seperate objects and the result turned out quite alright as well.

Answer (score 0):

Would not it be easier to start with one segment ...

- Array modifier
- Lattice modifier
- Curve modifier

Apply modifiers and manually adjust each one to real?

[image]

[image]

BTW ... Human Skeleton is quite accessible model for free, it depend on usage of course, but I think you can find some. Like [human skeleton](https://www.cgtrader.com/items/73986/download-page%20preview%20of%20spine) / separated spine [preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ofLHp.jpg) or [here not perfect but rigged](https://blendswap.com/blend/13239)  ...

Comment: Interesting, yes that surely would have been an easier approach to some extent. Basically building this thing to get better overall, so of course making it myself is the main goal.